# SQL - Simple Pivot Table while using Join statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to transpose my results from the following code which is joining multiple tables together. I know i need to use a PIVOT for this and it may be a simple fix, but i'm having huge difficultly getting the code to work. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT F.SetValue, D.Name FROM Device D
 INNER JOIN Location L ON D.LocationId = L.LocationId
 INNER JOIN Fitting F ON L.LocationId = F.LocationId
 INNER JOIN LocationTypeFitting LTF ON F.LocationTypeFittingId = LTF.LocationTypeFittingId
WHERE D.DeviceName = 'Device 1' AND LTF.Name LIKE '%Television%';
```

which prints the following results:

```
SetValue | Name
===========================
1        | TV_Power
1        | TV_Volume
1        | TV_Source
```

I need to return the values as below:

```
TV_Power | TV_Volume | TV_Source
================================
1        |  1         |  1
```

I know i'll also need a GROUP BY statement, but the the joining of additional tables is making this particular query increasingly difficult. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following two things:

1. Wrap the whole query in a sub-query and apply the [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) syntax.
2. Add another column, such as `DeviceName` from the `Device` table (or some other table), so that you can differentiate the rows once the pivot has been executed (I assume there will be more than one row).

it also shows where the `group by` would go in the comments.

```
select post_pivot.*
from (
    SELECT F.SetValue, D.Name, D.DeviceName FROM Device D
     INNER JOIN Location L ON D.LocationId = L.LocationId
     INNER JOIN Fitting F ON L.LocationId = F.LocationId
     INNER JOIN LocationTypeFitting LTF ON F.LocationTypeFittingId = LTF.LocationTypeFittingId
    WHERE D.DeviceName = 'Device 1' AND LTF.Name LIKE '%Television%'
    --group by (if needed)
) as pre_pivot
pivot (max(pre_pivot.set_value) for pre_pivot.Name in ([TV_Power], [TV_Volume], [TV_Source])) as post_pivot
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be sufficient or will give you enough to go on.

```
    SELECT 'DeviceType' as DeviceTYpe,* FROM
    (
    SELECT D.Name, F.SetValue  FROM Device D
     INNER JOIN Location L ON D.LocationId = L.LocationId
     INNER JOIN Fitting F ON L.LocationId = F.LocationId
     INNER JOIN LocationTypeFitting LTF ON F.LocationTypeFittingId = LTF.LocationTypeFittingId
    WHERE D.DeviceName = 'Device 1' AND LTF.Name LIKE '%Television%'
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT 
    (
    MAX(SetValue)
    FOR Name in ([TV_Power], [TV_Volume], [TV_Source])
    ) As PivotTable
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I also had to rename the column header at the end so your ''DeviceType' as Devicetype,'helped with that.